# Does Spark Streaming/Spark work like a while loop in the main() method?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

This is a very straight forward question:

I am using Spark Streaming in the following way:

```
private static int count=0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: sparkstreaminggetjson <hostname> <port>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

 SparkConf sparkConf = new  
SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("sparkstreaminggetjson");

JavaSparkContext sc=new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, 
Durations.seconds(1));

JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream(

args[0],Integer.parseInt(args[1]), StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);

count=count+1;

lines.print;

ssc.start();

ssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

Everytime a new 'batch time' begins, the variable lines gets a new value from a socket and prints it, and the variable count increases by 1.

My question is: right now I am declaring count outside of the main() , because if I do it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: sparkstreaminggetjson <hostname> <port>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

 //declare count here
 int count=0;
 SparkConf sparkConf = new  
SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("sparkstreaminggetjson");

JavaSparkContext sc=new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, 
Durations.seconds(1));

JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream(

args[0],Integer.parseInt(args[1]), StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);

count=count+1;

lines.print;

ssc.start();

ssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

everytime that a new batch time begins, the variable count gets reseted to 0.So, it basically works like a while loop.

Is there any way for me to declare count inside the main() method so that the Spark Streaming loop doesn't reset it to 0? And if so, where do I declare it?

Basically I want to know if when we create a Spark Context, we make the whole main() method behave like a while loop, or if there is a specific place in which this loop begins.

Thank you so much, I hope I wasn't confusing.

Comment: How are you observing that in case (1) the counter is increased?

Comment: Also, on case #1, the 'lines' variable does not get a new value on each streaming interval. It has only one value: A reference to the `socketTextStream` instantiated at creation time. What changes on each interval is the content of the underlying RDD, that is only accessible through operations on the DStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Spark Streaming does not do a "while loop" on a "main". Spark Streaming uses a scheduler to trigger registered [output operators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams) at the batch interval provided.

Those output operators will trigger the materialization of the underlying RDDs at every batch interval.  In this materialization process, the RDD operations will be executed in the Spark cluster.

The use of global static variables that are interact with whatever code that is serialized in the cluster will lead to unexpected behavior.

Spark is a distributed computing framework and its operations are oriented to that goal.  The classic transformations such as "map", "filter", ... will execute on pieces of data distributed across nodes in the cluster.

The closest equivalent of a "global variable" in Spark are [broadcast variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#accumulators-and-broadcast-variables) but those cannot be updated in the closures.

From the code provided, I understand that those are initial experiments to understand the Spark Streaming model. Take some time to study [related material](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) to fully understand how it's working. In this particular case, incrementing a static variable would work only in local mode because all code is executing on the same JVM, but that's not the goal for Spark Streaming.

Comment: thank you so much. You are right, this was just a very simple example I thought of to ilustrate my problem. Actually what I want to do, is to store the values from each RDD from the `lines` DStream, into ONE .txt file, one value per line.
Using `savetextasfiles.dstream()` I am able to save each RDD in the batch interval, but when another batch interval starts, the next RDD is stored in a different file, all with the same hdfs directory.
I thought about using FileWriter to save the values from each RDD in a given interval into one unique file.

Comment: But in each batch interval, FileWriter filew=new FileWriter(), repeats again and again, and I keep storing the values I want on top of each other in the same file. The result is that only one value is saved in my .txt file. It's the same when I try to store these values in an SQL database.
If I am being confusing I apologize, but thank you for the explanation, it was very needed.

Comment: @manuelmourato I see. In that case, use `FileWriter(filename, TRUE)` to append to a file. In the same tone as above, note that writing to a file in the local file system will only work when running on one node.